# How do I disable windows 8.1 gestures via regedit? (details)

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers, windows-registry, touchpad, charms-bar

I've followed others instructions.  For what I'd like to do, all I can find is the suggestion that updating the Synaptics driver will create the option in control panel>mouse>*.  I was successful in updating the drivers and I've restarted the computer.  I've thoroughly checked everything to do with touch/gestures/mouse/pointing devices, via control panel and the registry.  But, I've found nothing.  Any ideas?

Edit: I have an Acer e-15.  The Synaptic.com drivers failed to load, the Acer drivers loaded ok.

Edit2: I should add that the problem hasn't been solved.  Edit 1 was for info purposes.  My right-click area is so far in the middle of the touch-pad it's kind of silly.  I'd like to solve this problem so I can make an autohotkey script to get the menu button to work all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I searched in every relevant way.  Hours.  I finally found the solution, not by searching for what I was looking for, but something I wasn't: touchpad customization app.  The first result and the solution was this:
http://microsoftsofware.blogspot.com/2013/06/windows-81-for-touchpad-customization.html

Simplified: Win-W, Touchpad Settings.  That was it.  I'm still unclear as to why I now have two totally different control panels in Windows.